# Phaser login/signup form

Tags: javascript, facebook, game-engine, phaser-framework

I am developing a game in phaser but I am newbie yet. I want to create a login/signup/fb form in the main screen of the game. I did a html form in the index.html of phaser, but I have some doubts. How could I achieve the communication between the html and the scenes of phaser? I created global variables, but I think that is not a good practice.

Are there any options to use a state from html like MyGame.MainPage.startGame()?

This is the js script of the index, the function is associated to login button:

```
function login(){
    user = check_user_in_db();
    if(user){   //If the login is correct
        variable.startGame();
    }                  
}
```

This is the MainPage scene of Phaser:

```
/*********************NAMESPACE********************/
var MyGame = MyGame || {};
/**************************************************/

/******************INIT APP SCENE******************/
MyGame.MainPage = function(game)
{
    variable = this;
};

MyGame.MainPage.prototype =
{
    init: function()
    {

    }, // init

    preload: function()
    {
       //load Sprites
    }, //preload

    create: function()
    {
       //create Buttons 
    }, // create

    shutdown: function()
    {

    }, // shutdown

    startGame: function(){
        this.state.start("Menu", true, false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Phaser plugin
https://github.com/orange-games/phaser-input

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, finally I did it with it